# QT Cannot convert 'std::string' to 'std::string*' in initialization

Tags: c++, qt

I got some problems in creating my program for mobile using QT C++
When i run it i get this: `cannot convert 'std::string' to 'std::string*' in initialization`
And theres code for that error:

```
void rozvrh_b17::pars(string par) 
{ 
    data = new std::string*(par);
    printf(data->data());
}
//data and par are std::string
//without that new std::string*() it does similiar error
```

And i ask how to convert std::string to std::string* ??

EDIT:
i made this function to transfer data from one form to another and i need to remember that parameter...

Comment: Why are you using printf in c++?

Comment: btw, you have a memory leak with what your trying to do. Each time you use new you have to use delete later.

Comment: It's not a memory leak, it's a pointer to a temporary.  edit: well, I can see why you'd say that.  I see it differently.  It turns out that it's a nothing since the line is syntactically invalid.

Comment: @andre: You can't determine that for sure from the code shown, though it is of course highly suspect code *likely* to lead to a memory leak (assuming the obvious errors are fixed so that it compiles).

Comment: `&` converts `std::string` to `std::string*`, `data = &par;`. Whether that's right or not for you is hard to say.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley ops my bad. The code however seems to have a high potential for it. But if op manages the memory in the code he didn't show everything is good.

Comment: @andre: I wouldn't go so far as to say everything is good.  It's still terrible code, especially if this is a public member function, since there are no safeguards preventing the user from simply calling it twice in a row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downvoted you because this question shows no research effort.

```
string * data = &par;
```

`std::string*` is a pointer type.  You have a `std::string`, and it's address is the pointer type you want.  This is one of the first principles of using pointers.

Comment: Yep.  Addresses and dereferencing are a basic concept of C++.  Read this: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

Comment: Thanks your answer is right ! i will mark it as good answer when i should do that (i need to wait 4 mins)

Answer (score 0):

What do you really try to do?

If you just want to print the string then this should work:

```
void rozvrh_b17::pars(string par) 
{ 
    printf(par.c_str());
}
```

If you want to create a copy of string on the heap then you need this:

```
std::string* data = new std::string(par);
```

but that doesn't make much sense.

Comment: i made it to transfer data from one form to another

Comment: `printf(par.c_str());` is dangerous if the string contains percents. `printf("%s", par.c_str());` perhaps.

Comment: john, yes, you are right. but that is not the point of the question - I feel that OP misses a lot of basic stuff anyway.

Comment: @GemHunter1 What do you mean 'one form to another'. It's not very clear.

Comment: i got two Forms in this app and i need to transfer that data to second

Comment: your code shows a call to print the content of an `std::string` and nothing related to forms.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign a string from a pointer to string. In this particular case I see several things.

1. You don't need a copy at all - simply use par right away
2. You better make par a const ref: `void rozvrh_b17::pars(const string& par)`
3. You should use only `string` whaen calling new otherwise you create a pointer to string. So do: `data = new std::string(par);`